# Magnetic Locks mods

Tags: arduino, magnetics, security

What about magnetic locks? Two questions..
 Does armature plate need be exact size as magnetic mate? Id like to get a bigger one milled so i dont have to use lasers to check perfect alignment.  Secondly, can one up voltage 20% for a short period if perimeter alarms indicate trouble via dpdt relay?

Id use arduinos

Comment: `can one up voltage 20% for a short period` ... what are the manufacturer's specs?

Comment: `Does armature plate need be exact size as magnetic mate?` ... i am pretty sure that it would stick just as well to the the side of a battle ship.

Comment: You mean an Arduino would drive a MOSFET or N-channel Darlington transistor which drives your electromagnetic lock. There is a low pull-in current, a very high 'grab' current, and a high 'locked' current. It is about not cooking the electromagnet with too much continuous current.

Answer (score 1):

Size of armature: it should be as big as the mating surface of the lock, slightly bigger will not be a problem, if it's too heavy it may not find correct alignment when it mates.

Changing the voltage is unlikely to improve anything.
the maximum force is determined by how much steel is in the core, once the core is saturated with magnetism adding more current in the windings will not make the electromagnet significantly stronger.

these items are mass-produced the bean-counters have had the engineers optimize the amount of steel and copper in there, there's no spare capacity available by over-volting them.

If you need a lock with 2000kgF pull strength buy one with 2000kgF pull strength, don't buy a 1500kgF one and try to fake it.

(yeah, I know engineering units are newtons, but all the advertising literature uses kilogram, or pound, force)

Answer (score 0):

1) a flexible armature plate to get perfect mating is better if alignment is hard to maintain as any edge gap reduces holding power.

2) The plate can be any size larger than sender.  Making it swivel is a mechanical feature.  This is how door magnets work with a case to prevent magnets from falling out but adjust to door plate.

3)  Yes 20% extra V is ok limited by thermal energy with a time duration.  Joules of heat = I^2 * DCR * t

Temp rise depends on ...
delta T rise = Joules *  thermal resistance and mass like an RC rise time to a target temp..

Comment: Oh! Very well! I will need to take mechanical or a  optoelectronic solution of mating. The armature requires some seasonal adjustment, so to allow that, means it can also slip out of place. Continuity is almost always made, still worth a pin to check. Ill dump the big plate idea and dig around for a slightly higher voltage psu.